# asp.net global synclock object

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, synclock

is there a way in asp.net to make sure that a certain threaded sub is not run twice concurrently, no matter what?

the code i have now is

```
Public Class CheckClass
ReadOnly Property CheckSessionsLock As Object
    Get
        If HttpRuntime.Cache("CheckSessionsLock") Is Nothing Then HttpRuntime.Cache("CheckSessionsLock") = New Object
        Return HttpRuntime.Cache("CheckSessionsLock")
    End Get
End Property
Sub TryThreads()
    Dim thread = New Thread(AddressOf TryLock)
    thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest
    thread.Start()
End Sub
Sub TryLock()
    SyncLock CheckSessionsLock
        DoTrace("entered locker")
        For x = 0 To 10000
        Next
        DoTrace("exiting locker")
    End SyncLock
    DoTrace("exited locker")
End Sub
End Class
```

if i run this code on every page then several times the code overlaps. the DoTrace function in the code simply writes the message to a table.

the messages in the table should appear in order (entered,exiting,exited) again and again, but in reality, they don't. i get like entered, exiting,entered,exited,exiting...

this means that the synclock is not complete. is that true?

if so, how can we implement a complete synclock on a block of code, across requests and across sessions?

**EDIT:** i need this lock, as the real code will be sending emails, according to a list of mailing types in a db. after each mailing type is sent, its marked, then it continues with the next mailing. i cant have in middle of processing, another thread should see this mailing as unprocessed.

please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the HttpRuntime Cache have you considered using a static variable?

Just as a note (it might be helpful to explain why you want this functionality) your website is not going to be very scalable if this can only be run once at a time.

Comment: hi thanks. yes ive tried. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851591/asp-net-multithreading-with-synclock. also ive edited my question to include the reasoning. thanks.

Comment: Static variables are shared across the whole AppDomain which is the same as being across the whole application.

Comment: I would expect your code to print out Entered and Exit one after the other, but due to the way the SyncLock works there is a chance that it will then print the next Entered before the final Exited

Comment: aha! u mean i should only be checking "entered" and "exiting"? as the exited is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, because "exited" occurs outside of the synclock block.

Comment: now its working!! thanks!!!. i mean it was probably working till now as well, just i didn't understand this last point u just explained. thanks a million! hats off to you!

Answer (score 1):

In C# (sorry, don't know VB syntax) I use this:

```
private static readonly object Padlock = new object();
```

- It's a field, not a property,
- It's static (in VB, that's "shared" if I'm not mistaken) so it's the same throughout the entire application
- It's initialised once as soon as you use this class, not when you explicitly use the field.

With your property/cache version, you could have two threads trying to get the lock-object and each creating a different one:

- Thread 1 checks the cache and doesn't find the object
- Thread 1 is parked
- Thread 2 checks the cache, doesn't find the object
- Thread 2 creates the object and caches it, retrieves it again and returns from the property
- Thread 1 resumes
- Thread 1 creates a new object and caches it, retrieves it again and returns a different lock object than thread 2 uses
- Any further threads will use the lock object of thread 1